# Getting layer sizes wrong in matlab CNN

Tags: matlab, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am trying to reproduce the convolution network described in https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.01683 .

Overview of their setup:

[image]

However, I seem to run into an obstacle when trying to combine results from different filters. 
In the paper, the authors have a "stacking" layer, where 20 different filtered 1D signals are stacked, to create a sort of spectrogram, which is then fed to another convolutional layer. How does one do a similar thing in matlab? Below is what I have tried, and the error message that I get:

Input:

```
  inputLayer=imageInputLayer([1 6000]);
  c1=convolution2dLayer([1 200],20,'stride',1);
  p1=maxPooling2dLayer([1 20],'stride',10);
  c2=convolution2dLayer([20 30],400,'numChannels',20);
  p2=maxPooling2dLayer([1 10],'stride',[1 2]);
  f1=fullyConnectedLayer(500);
  f2=fullyConnectedLayer(500);
  s1=softmaxLayer;
  outputLayer=classificationLayer;

  convnet=[inputLayer; c1; p1; c2; p2; f1; f2; s1;outputLayer]

  opts = trainingOptions('sgdm');
  convnet = trainNetwork(allData',labels,convnet,opts);
```

Output:

```
  convnet = 

    9x1 Layer array with layers:

       1   ''   Image Input             1x6000x1 images with 'zerocenter' normalization
       2   ''   Convolution             20 1x200 convolutions with stride [1  1] and padding [0  0]
       3   ''   Max Pooling             1x20 max pooling with stride [10  10] and padding [0  0]
       4   ''   Convolution             400 20x30 convolutions with stride [1  1] and padding [0  0]
       5   ''   Max Pooling             1x10 max pooling with stride [1  2] and padding [0  0]
       6   ''   Fully Connected         500 fully connected layer
       7   ''   Fully Connected         500 fully connected layer
       8   ''   Softmax                 softmax
       9   ''   Classification Output   cross-entropy
  Error using nnet.cnn.layer.Layer>iInferSize (line 261)
  Layer 5 is expected to have a different size.

  Error in nnet.cnn.layer.Layer.inferParameters (line 53)
                  layers = iInferSize(layers, i, inputSize);

  Error in trainNetwork (line 61)
  layers = nnet.cnn.layer.Layer.inferParameters(layers);
```

The error message is for layer 5, but I suspect it has to do with layer 4, where the "stacking" takes place.
Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fundamental problem here is that convolution2dLayer does not understand 1D inputs. By going into the nitty-gritty details, it turns out that the inputsizes very quickly become meaningless (negative number of rows, for instance).